# Java RegEx that matches exactly 8 digits

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple RegEx that was supposed to look for 8 digits number:

```
String number = scanner.findInLine("\\d{8}");
```

But it turns out, it also matches 9 and more digits number.
How to fix this RegEx to match exactly 8 digits?

For example: 12345678 should be matched, while
1234567, and 123456789 should not.

Comment: Could you post sample examples that should be matched and not matched?

Comment: Depends in which context. But yours will match in any 8+ digit context because it is not anchored or restricted with any boundaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

**`\b`** is known as word boundary it will say to your regex that numbers end after 8

```
String number = scanner.findInLine("\\b\\d{8}\\b");
```

Comment: Don't you need a word boundary at the beginning as well? otherwise you can still match the last eight digits of a longer number

Comment: This will never find 8 digits in between `_`.

Answer (score 27):

I think this is simple and it works:

```
String regEx = "^[0-9]{8}$";
```

- `^` - starts with
- `[0-9]` - use only digits (you can also use `\d`)
- `{8}` - use 8 digits
- `$` - End here. Don't add anything after 8 digits.

Answer (score 11):

Your regex will match 8 digits anywhere in the string, even if there are other digits after these 8 digits.

To match 8 consecutive digits, that are not enclosed with digits, you need to use *lookarounds*:

```
String reg = "(?<!\\d)\\d{8}(?!\\d)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tW0wY6/17)

**Explanation**:

- `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind that will fail a match if there is a digit before 8 digits
- `\d{8}` 8 digits
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails a match if there is a digit right after the 8 digits matched with the `\d{8}` subpattern.

Comment: among all solutions only this one works,thanks a lot, I found it after 3 hr